# Is it possible to yield all subcollections of an IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, memory-management

What I mean is that if I have a set like

```
{ 1, 2, 3 }
```

then all the subsets are

```
{  },
{ 1 }, 
{ 2 }, 
{ 3 },
{ 1, 2 },
{ 2, 3 },
{ 1, 3 },
{ 1, 2, 3 }
```

which is `2^3` of them because the set has size `3`. Any solution I think of requires "remembering" the previous subsets up to size `n - 1` where `n` is the length of the set. For example, I have a solution I wrote that looks like

```
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> AllSubcollections<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        // The empty set is always a subcollection
        yield return new List<T>() { };

        T[] arr = source.ToArray();
        IEnumerable<int> indices = Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length);
        var last = new List<HashSet<int>>(new List<HashSet<int>>() { new HashSet<int>() });
        for(int k = 1; k < arr.Length; ++k)
        {
            var next = new List<HashSet<int>>(new List<HashSet<int>>());
            foreach(HashSet<int> hs in last)
            {
                foreach(int index in indices)
                {
                    if(!hs.Contains(index))
                    {
                        var addition = hs.Concat(new List<int> { index });
                        yield return addition.Select(i => arr[i]);
                        next.Add(new HashSet<int>(addition));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Notice how that assumes that `source` can fit in an array, and assumes that a `HashSet` can hold the previous subcollections.

Given that `IEnumerable<T>` can `yield` an arbitrary number of results (even an infinite amount), is it possible to write a solution that does this for the subset problem?

Comment: @C.McCoyIV: His solution calls .ToArray() on its input and wants to know if its possible to write an algorithm for this that doesn't explode immediately on an infinite feed.

Answer (score 0):

You point out the flaw yourself in your question. We have `IEnumerable`s that don't terminate on archive.

In fact this is still possible if you carefully write your set enumerator so that it returns another `IEnumerable`. This won't terminate if the source doesn't but that's not all that bad of a problem. All subsets of a billion rows will run too long anyway so you'll probably never hit that `OutOfMemoryException`.

```
public static IEnumerable<IReadOnlyList<T>> AllSubcollections<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    // The empty set is always a subcollection
    yield return new List<T>() { };

    List<T> priors = new List<T>();
    List<bool> includes = new List<bool>(); // Need a bitvector to get past 64 elements.
    while (source.MoveNext())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < includes.Count; ++i)
            includes[i] = false;
        // Always return the newest item in any set. This avoids dupes.
        priors.Add(source.Current);
        priors.Add(true);

        bool breakout;
        do {
            List<T> set = new List<T>();
            for (int i = 0; i < priors.Count; ++i)
                if (includes[i])
                     set[i] = includes[i];
            yield return (IReadOnlyList<T>)set;

            // Bitvector increment
            breakout = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < priors.Count; ++i) {
                if (!includes[i]) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
                        includes[j] = 0;
                    includes[i] = true;
                    breakout = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (!breakout);            
    }
}
```